# my macro runs faster when run with button but slows down when run from developer pane

Tags: excel, vba

Running the same piece of VBA code in Excel in two different ways. 1. Form control button(time - 1.5 seconds). 2. running the macro manually (time - 6 seconds)

Below is the code. Code is to Auto Group the rows

```
Sub Autogroup()
time1 = Timer

 Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer

 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearOutline

    For i = 9 To LastRow

    'For i,#,# - the (#)number is the column number for the GROUP header on the excel

        If Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then

            Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Group

        ElseIf Cells(i, 13) <> "" Then

            Cells(i, 13).EntireRow.Group

        ElseIf Cells(i, 22) <> "" Then

            Cells(i, 22).EntireRow.Group

        End If

    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Cells(1, 1).Select

 'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 MsgBox Timer - time1

End Sub
```

Comment: And the code for the form control button only does `AutoGroup` and nothing else?

Comment: yes only Auto group - it is assigned to the same Macro                                 I even tried using the below manual calculation but still no improvement in run time               
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    * code here*
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Comment: TBH I'm hesitant to suggest any improvements, seeing you're using `Integer` (Int16) to store row numbers, use `Select` and `Selection`, implicitly work off `ActiveSheet`, make implicit default member calls on `Range` and assume the value is convertible to a string for comparison (hint: a single `#N/A`  will blow everything up), and `time1` isn't declared, which hints at `Option Explicit` not being specified - all of which are much more pressing and impactful than any performance concerns one might have over a 5-6 seconds runtime.

Comment: One thing that could be different is what sheet is active when the code runs. Is `ActiveSheet` the sheet with the button when you invoke `AutoGroup` from the immediate pane?